# Appending a dataset to other dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Dataset1

col1 col2
---- ----
1    a
2    b
3    c

Dataset2

col1
----
doctor
engineer
programmer

I want this in grid view like this

col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
1     a    doctor
2    b    engineer
3    c    Programmer

Comment: create new column in dataset1(actually columns is in DataTable and DataSets holds tables) and add values from dataset2

Comment: why not implement it at your dataaccess layer ?

Comment: So you want to merge two Tables? Data set don't have columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , you have no need to merge 2 DataTables

You can use linq instead.

```
        var datasource = from r1 in table1.AsEnumerable().Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i })
                         from r2 in table2.AsEnumerable().Select((r, i) => new { Value = r, Index = i })
                         where r1.Index == r2.Index 
                         select new
                         {
                             col1 = r1.Value["col1"].ToString(),
                             col2 = r1.Value["col2"].ToString(),
                             col3 = r2.Value["col1"].ToString(),
                         };
```

Then , Bound it like.

```
datagridview.datasource = datasource ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two tables related, the apropiated way to implement this in in the **same Dataset**.

This is an alternative to linq method.

To do this, you have to use DataRelation
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datarelation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You have to create, of course, an ForeignKeyContraint to make this work.

Here's an example:

```
 Dim relation As DataRelation
Dim ParentColumn As DataColumn
Dim ChildColumn As DataColumn
Dim foreignkey As ForeignKeyConstraint

ParentColumn = Me.dataset.Tables("table1").Columns(PKTable1)
ChildColumn = Me.dataset.Tables("table2").Columns(FKTable2)
foreignkey = New ForeignKeyConstraint("fkey_table1_table2", ParentColumn, ChildColumn)


                foreignkey.DeleteRule = Rule.Cascade
                foreignkey.UpdateRule = Rule.Cascade                
               foreignkey.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade


relation = New DataRelation("Relation_table1_table2", ParentColumn, ChildColumn, True)


 table2.Constraints.Add(foreignkey)


 Me.dataset.Relations.Add(relation)
```

Now you simply specify **Table2** as the **DataSource** of the **DataGrid**

```
datagrid.datasource=dataset
datagrid.datamember= "table2"
```